# Can faded stamped concrete be stained to match rest of patio?

Tags: concrete

Stamped concrete patio has severely faded - assume from sun and water runoff from canopy? Rest of patio and back steps looks great.It has been sealed several times over the years. 
How do we restore colour? Does this require a professional? [image]

Comment: I have DIY'd concrete stain and sealing and it's not hard at all.  The issue is trying to match what you have now, and it needs to be done as good as possible the first time.  Pro might be your best bet, but someone might know some tricks.